# Trigger that search inserted values in another table

Tags: loops, plsql, triggers, plpgsql

I need to upload info from external databases into mine periodically.
These are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    id character varying primary key,
    name character varying UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE B
(
    id character varying primary key,
    name character varying 
)

CREATE TABLE C
(
    id character varying REFERENCES B(id),
    name character varying REFERENCES A(name)
)
```

To add some insight, A.name are known designations and B.name are texts that may contain or not those known designations. The matches are saved in table c.
I do this work in R when uploading table b but I need a trigger that insert the new matches in C whenever a row is inserted in A (updates and deletes are solved with a cascade).

I am thinking in something like this (pseudocode):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
   AFTER INSERT
   ON A FOR EACH ROW
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 -- Loop throug all INSERTED.name
 -- Search each INSERTED.name value in B.name with: like '%INSERTED.name%'
 -- When found, insert in C both id and INSERTED.name 
END;
```

My biggest problem is that I can't figure out how to make the iterations properly in PLPGSQL or if this is a correct aproximation.
Will it be better to just call the R script that loads the needed tables and map them again instead of using the inserted data?

Thanks and sorry if my question is not clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example how to write trigger function and how create triggers for tables:

```
CREATE FUNCTION a_after_insert() 
   RETURNS TRIGGER 
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
declare 
    b_id varchar;
begin
    select 
        id into b_id 
    from b 
    where 
        b."name" like '%' || new."name" || '%';
    
    -- if record not found then b_id will be null;
    if (b_id is not null) then 
        insert into c (id, "name") values (b_id, new."name");   
    end if; 
    return new;
END;
$$

create trigger a_after_insert_trigger
after insert 
  on a
  for each row 
  execute procedure a_after_insert();
```

For each row in PostgreSQL - this means that even if 10 records are inserted into the table at once, the trigger works once for each row, so there is no need for a loop.

Only here there may be a problem, since we are searching like in `b` table, its result may be not one but several rows. You can also write it like this if you want:

```
CREATE FUNCTION a_after_insert() 
   RETURNS TRIGGER 
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
begin
    
    insert into c (id, "name")
    select b.id, new.name   
    from b 
    where 
        b."name" like '%' || new."name" || '%';
    
    return new;
END;
$$
```